# Javascript POST request not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, request

i created POST request, but its not working. 
When i 'Try it out!' in Swagger UI its works.
So here is my script:

```
function myFunction() {
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'localhost:8080/abc/abc',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
            "abc1": "abc",
            "abc2": "abc@abc.abc",
            "abc3": "abc",
            "abc4": "abc",
            "abc5": "abc",
            "abc6": "abc"
        }),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function () {
        alert("Success!");
    }
})};
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a post request, it looks the URL relative to your current path in the browser.

Try changing `localhost:8080/abc/abc` to `/abc/abc`.

Hope it helps.